# How can I use the Material UI theme provider in React if my application has both class components and functional components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am currently working on a React app with class components, and when I add some components I make sure they are functional components instead. I also replaced a few class components by functional components in the application. However, the theme I defined in the highest-level component is only being applied to class components.

My theme is defined in App.js, the highest-level component:

```
import { ThemeProvider, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

...

render() {
        const theme = createTheme({
            palette: {
                primary: {
                    main: '#23A455',
                    contrastText: '#000000',
                },
                secondary: {
                    main: '#7c22a3',
                    contrastText: '#ffffff',
                },
                failure: {
                    main: red[300],
                    subtle: red[100],
                    hover: red[200]
                },
                disease: {
                    main: amber[300],
                    subtle: amber[100],
                    hover: amber[200]
                }
            },
        }, zhCN);
        const { classes } = this.props;
        return (
            <userContext.Provider value={this.state.user}>
                <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                    ... rest of the application here
                </ThemeProvider>
            </userContext.Provider>

...

export default withStyles(styles)(withRouter(App));
```

And class components access the theme in this way:

```
import {withStyles} from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = theme => ({
    media: {
        maxWidth: '100%'
    },
    ...
});

export default withTranslation()(withStyles(styles, {withTheme: true})(ComponentName));
```

I am trying to access the theme in my functional components through the useTheme() hook. However, the theme that I defined in App.js does not apply unless I change the import `import { ThemeProvider as MuiThemeProvider, withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';` to `import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';`.

When I do this, my class components no longer use the theme I defined, but my functional components do. Is there any way to use the Material UI theme provider in a way that works with both functional and class components?

Answer (score 2):

Good question. You can try to do it like this, I hope it what you need.

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';

// Define your theme here
const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#23A455',
      contrastText: '#000000',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#7c22a3',
      contrastText: '#ffffff',
    },
    failure: {
      main: red[300],
      subtle: red[100],
      hover: red[200]
    },
    disease: {
      main: amber[300],
      subtle: amber[100],
      hover: amber[200]
    }
  },
});

// Use the theme in your functional component
function MyFunctionalComponent() {
  const classes = useStyles(); // You can define your styles here using the makeStyles hook
  const theme = useTheme(); // You can access the theme here using the useTheme hook

  // Your component code here
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div className={classes.root}>Your component content here</div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}

// Use the theme in your class component
class MyLegacyClassComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const theme = this.props.theme;

    // Your component code here
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <div className={classes.root}>Your component content here</div>
      </ThemeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(MyLegacyClassComponent);
```